# What is the analysis techniques for comparing two sets of ratings

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, agreement-statistics

Say, I have collected 50 comments. For each comment, I am planning to get 10 ratings from non-expert raters for the following criteria: "interesting vs. not interesting". Based on the plurality of those ratings, I will determine if a comment is "interesting" or not. For example, 6 out of 10 raters rated comment #1 as "interesting", I assume comment #1 is interesting

The thing that complicates the matter a bit is that I also have experts (the ones who are trained/versed in giving such ratings) rate those comments in a similar fashion as mentioned above.

My question is: I would also like to know if I can use non-experts (less costly) to rate the comments instead of paying more for experts. What kind of statistical/mathematical calculation can I do to find that out? Is there a calculation that tells us how much of two sets of ratings overlap/agree?

Thank you very much.

Comment: One way would be to assess, by intraclass correlation corfficient, the degree of agreement among the experts, and among the non-experts, and then to test if the two coefficients differ significantly.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you. Is there an online example/resource that would explain what you said with a toy problem? I've read up intraclass correlation, but not having a statistics background, still can't figure out how to test "if the two coefficients differ significantly". Thanks for the suggestion again.